# Add the text to the second line using pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to add text below an existing `div` id. How ever the `white-space: pre-wrap;` or adding html tags such as content:`"\<br/> Lorem ipsome."` does not move the text to the next line.

`HTML` and `CSS` part:

```css
div.brand-amenity-value.economy.YV span.amenity-value:lang(en)::after {
    margin-left: 0px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    content: '<p> (One date change free) </p>';
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-amenity-value economy YV" style="height: 70px; background-color: #f2f5e6;">
<div><span class="spark-assistive-text">Yes</span></div>
<span class="amenity-value"><span data-translation="AED 100">AED 100</span></span></div>
```

Screen-shot of the text that needs to be on second line:

[image]

Comment: just define display block in your css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can consider `position:absolute`

```css
div.brand-amenity-value.economy.YV span.amenity-value::after {
  content: '(One date change free) ';
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div.brand-amenity-value.economy.YV  span.amenity-value{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-amenity-value economy YV" style="height: 70px; background-color: #f2f5e6;">
  <div><span class="spark-assistive-text">Yes</span></div>
  <span class="amenity-value"><span data-translation="AED 100">AED 100</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: a big thanks, actually adding position:absolute; worked like a charm, I did a few other adjustments and now the issue is fixed.

Comment: I did but I am getting the error... Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Accepted the answer now ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `<p>` or `<br>` tag. The pseudo-element `::after` itself can be styled. In this case set `display` to `block` would work:

```css
div.brand-amenity-value.economy.YV span.amenity-value::after {
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: '(One date change free)';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-amenity-value economy YV" style="height: 70px; background-color: #f2f5e6;">
  <div><span class="spark-assistive-text">Yes</span></div>
  <span class="amenity-value"><span data-translation="AED 100">AED 100</span></span>
</div>
```

Or if this solution is not an option somehow, you can use `\A` to add a new line:

```css
div.brand-amenity-value.economy.YV span.amenity-value::after {
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: '\A(One date change free)';
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-amenity-value economy YV" style="height: 70px; background-color: #f2f5e6;">
  <div><span class="spark-assistive-text">Yes</span></div>
  <span class="amenity-value"><span data-translation="AED 100">AED 100</span></span>
</div>
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content

Comment: Both the display: block and a/ are ignored by the site. So I am not sure if there is some other way to get this working.

Comment: if you run the code snippet you will find they work as SO snippets. There could be some other troublesome styles elsewhere.

Comment: I noticed there is a `lang(en)` selector in your CSS but it's not there in the HTML, could this be the reason? Note that I removed that from the code snippet in the answer to get it working